Incorrect MySQL client library version on windows ruby
I'm on ruby, running on a windows.
The gemfile has this gem :
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.5.5'

Whenever i'm try to do a rails command, I have this error

`rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'mysql2'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
Gem Load Error is: Incorrect MySQL client library version! This gem was compiled for 10.8.8 but the client library is 3.3.8.

I don't understand how gem has version 10.8.8 for mysql2 ?
I've tried all the solutions I could see but none of them works :

gem pristine mysql2 is not working
uninstalling / reinstalling is not working

Any help is appreciated, thanks a lot

You need to pay attention to your tags, this question is about MySQL not Postgres. I changed the tags.

Known Issue: https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/1348; https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/1361; https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/1366

Beating the dead horse a bit here but but do yourself a huge favor and install wsl2 and your Linux distro of choice. Trying to get Rails and all your dependencies running on Windows itself is a complete waste of time unless you plan on actually depoying to a Windows server. It's free and will save you so much misery.
